Why is the memory address the same for these two variables?
when i run this program the memory address of variables x and y are the same.
my best guess would be that since the variables exist in functions that are called on they only exist when theyre called on so they can use the same memory location. does this make sense?
#include <stdio.h>

void foo1(int);
void foo2(int);

void foo1(int xval)
{
    int x;
    x = xval;
    int *ptr;
    ptr = &x;
    printf("address of x: %p\n", ptr);
    printf("value of x: %d\n", *ptr);
}

void foo2(int yval)
{
    int y;
    y = yval;
    int *ptr;
    ptr = &y;
    printf("address of y: %p\n", ptr);
    printf("value of y: %d\n", *ptr);
}

int main()
{
    foo1(7);
    foo2(11);
    return 0;
}


yes, it is how variables on stack behave

Relevant information that would have made this question unnecessary: What and where are the stack and heap? and Explain the concept of a stack frame in a nutshell.

Reusing space for variables with separate lifetimes is common. For a large program this is important to reduce the total size.

Storage (memory) for an object declared int x; or int y; inside a block is reserved only during the portion of program execution from when execution of the block starts until it ends. Outside of that time, the storage may be reused for other objects or even other purposes.
So two objects whose storage is reserved at different times during program execution, without any overlap, may use the same storage and may have the same address.
A block includes the function body { … }. (There are often also sub-blocks inside functions, discussed below.)
You may often see people refer to these as “stack“ variables, because a hardware stack is a common way of implementing the variables defined inside a function, but the C standard does not require this, and they may be implemented by other means. The fact that their memory may be reused outside of the reserved time remains true whether they are implemented via a stack or via other means.
Supplement
Blocks include { … } inside a function and if, switch, for, while, and do statements and their immediate substatements.
